# MongoDB Aggregation Framework performance slow over millions of documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

## background

Our system is carrier grade and extremely robust, it has been load tested to handle 5000 transactions per second, and for each transaction a document is inserted into a single MongoDB collection (no updates or queries in this application, it is write-only).
That amounts to ~700MM documents per day which is our benchmark.

The MongoDB deployment is not yet sharded, we have 1x replicaset with 1 master and 2 slaves all of which are type m2.2xlarge instances on ec2. 
Each instance is backed by a 1TB RAID0 stripe consisting of 8 volumes (no PIOPS).
We are using the node-mongodb-native driver with c++ native BSON parser for optimal write performance and have attempted to model the document structure accordingly.

## note

- Documents are tiny (120 bytes)
- The document includes a “time bucket” (h[our], d[ay], m[onth], y[ear]) along with the “t[ime]” field
- We have an index on the collection to query by “c[ustomer]” and “a” which is a highly random but non-unique tag
- We have looked into partitioning data into separate collections, though in this example all data is hot.
- We are also looking into pre-aggregation though this cannot be done in realtime.

## requirement

- For reporting we need to calculate the amount of unique “a” tags per month, along with their totals by customer over any given period
- A report takes about 60sec to run over a sample (full collection) of 9.5MM documents stored over 2 hours. Details below:

#### document

```
{
  _id: ObjectID(),
  a: ‘string’,
  b: ‘string’,
  c: ‘string’ or <int>,
  g: ‘string’ or <not_exist>,
  t: ISODate(),
  h: <int>,
  d: <int>,
  m: <int>,
  y: <int>
}
```

#### index

```
col.ensureIndex({ c: 1, a: 1, y: 1, m: 1, d: 1, h: 1 });
```

#### aggregation query

```
col.aggregate([
    { $match: { c: 'customer_1', y: 2013, m: 11 } },
    { $group: { _id: { c: '$c', y: '$y', m: '$m' }, a: { $addToSet: '$a' }, t: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $unwind: '$a' },
    { $group: { _id: { c: '$_id.c', y: '$_id.y', m: '$_id.m', t: '$t' }, a: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { '_id.m': 1 } },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            c: '$_id.c',
            y: '$_id.y', 
            m: '$_id.m',
            a: 1,
            t: '$_id.t'
        }
    },
    { $group: { _id: { c: '$c', y: '$y' }, monthly: { $push: { m: '$m', a: '$a', t: '$t' } } } },
    { $sort: { '_id.y': 1 } },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            c: '$_id.c',
            y: '$_id.y', 
            monthly: 1
        }
    },
    { $group: { _id: { c: '$c' }, yearly: { $push: { y: '$y', monthly: '$monthly' } } } },
    { $sort: { '_id.c': 1 } },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            c: '$_id.c',
            yearly: 1
        }
    }    
]);
```

#### aggregation result

```
[
    {
        "yearly": [
            {
                "y": 2013,
                "monthly": [
                    {
                        "m": 11,
                        "a": 3465652,
                        "t": 9844935
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "c": "customer_1"
    }
]

63181ms
```

#### aggregation explain

```
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor c_1_a_1_y_1_m_1_d_1_h_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 9844935,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 9844935,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 101,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 9845036,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : true,
        "nYields" : 27,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 32039,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "c" : [ [ "customer_1", "customer_1" ] ],
                "a" : [ [ { "$minElement" : 1 }, { "$maxElement" : 1 } ] ],
                "y" : [ [ 2013, 2013 ] ],
                "m" : [ [ 11, 11 ] ],
                "d" : [ [ { "$minElement" : 1 }, { "$maxElement" : 1 } ] ],
                "h" : [ [ { "$minElement" : 1 }, { "$maxElement" : 1 } ] ]
        }
}
```

## questions

1. Given the high frequency of inserts, and our need to perform ranged aggregation queries over time. Is the time bucket good practice considering the application can insert 30MM documents in a single hour period?
2. We were of the understanding that MongoDB can query billions of documents in seconds:

   - Surely our aggregation query over 9.5MM documents could return in 1sec or so?
   - Are we using the right technique to achieve this and if not where should we be focusing our efforts to getting report results almost instantly?
   - Is it possible without sharding at this stage?
3. Would MapReduce (parallel) be a better alternative?

Comment: 10M docs processed in 60 seconds is 6 microseconds per doc.  That feels about right.  Sounds like some background MapReduce jobs are in order to pre-aggregate as much as possible.

Comment: this is probably a more complex question than can be answered here, but there are several indicators in the explain - 32 seconds was spent scanning the index. that means the other 31 were spent doing the rest of the aggregation.  I suspect that there are more efficient ways to store the document and index (reducing their size) - is there a reason "a" is where it is in the index (rather than at the end?)

Comment: @JohnnyHK I tend to agree with you that background pre-aggregation is necessary, though that said I still believe there is room for improvement in the speed of this query.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky by more efficient ways of storage are you referring to partitioning the collection, or the actual size of the document which really couldn't be made much smaller other than removing the time bucket. In relation to this, "a"'s position in the index is legacy since prior to the time bucket's existence, the index was { c: 1, a: 1, t: 1 } and the aggregation query was ranged ($gte, $lt). Our understanding is that in this case, the ranged field should be at the end of the index. Is the use of a time bucket generally a more performant model than querying on time fields?

Comment: BTW index scan time drops to 25sec with "a" positioned at the end of the index, total query time 52sec.

Comment: Does your index fit into RAM? You mention you don't have any IOPS on your disks. Given its a covered query (indexOnly) it should be a lot faster than that. I would take a look at your disk stats to see if the IO is the bottleneck due to data being paged in and out.

Comment: @Matt Server instance has 35GB RAM, index size is ~1GB. Is there benefit to having a covered query when the entire index is scanned?

Comment: the key is this aggregation is index only, so reducing the size of the index or the portion of the index the aggregation needs to scan would speed it up.  I think that if you added {$sort:{c:1,y:1,m:1}} along with {$match} that it would speed things up - care to try it?

Comment: I think there may be one more inefficiency in the pipeline - there may be a place where you can reduce the size of result set earlier.

Comment: @ashley brener Does all your working set fit in memory? Have a look at your page fault stats or IO stats to see if its still hitting the disk. Using a covered query should be faster even if you are scanning the entire index because it avoids hitting the disk as long as your indexes all fit in memory.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, as per your advice and on recommendation by Jay Runkel (Senior Solutions Architect @MongoDB), I have modified the index as col.ensureIndex({c:1,y:1,a:1}) and added your {$sort:{c:1,y:1,m:1}} immediately after the 1st $match. This results in an overall query time of ~50sec.

Comment: @matt page faults are 0 and there appears to be no IO activity during the time of this query.

Comment: @ashley what happens if you run the aggregation query on a secondary? Same performance?

Comment: @Matt, good question though we are having unrelated issues with the driver consistently reading from secondary. So the results look the same but cannot always guarantee the path where the result set comes from. Working on this separately ...

Comment: @AshleyBrener Curious, what ultimately happened to this?

Answer (score 7):

You wonder why your aggregation is taking so "long".  Aside from the points made by @Avish in his answer (you are doing some unnecessary steps) you also have to consider your physical resources and where the time is going.

Here is part of your "explain":

> ```
>     "n" : 9844935,
>     "nscannedObjects" : 0,
>     "nscanned" : 9844935,
>     "scanAndOrder" : false,
>     "indexOnly" : true,
>     "nYields" : 27,
>     "millis" : 32039,
> ```

Things of note are the fact that the aggregation took 32 seconds (not 50), it never had to fetch a single document as it got all of the information from the index itself.  It didn't have to do any in-memory sorts.  But it did have to yield 27 times...   Why is that?  There are two reasons that reader processes yield - one is when there is a write waiting (writers take precedence and long running reads have to yield to them) or there was a page fault - all operations must yield when any data they are trying to access is not in RAM (this is to prevent a process from blocking others from doing work while they are waiting for their data to be loaded into RAM).

Questions that come to mind are: was the DB cold?  Do the indexes fit in RAM?  Were there writes happening at the same time that the reads had to contend with?

I would check that the index can fit in RAM, run [the "touch" command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) to make sure it *is* in RAM, simplify my aggregation pipeline not to do unnecessary work and then run it again, a couple of times in a row and see how the timings look then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to `$unwind` the `a` values and why you need to group by the total at any point. This also seems to be buggy since for each unwound `a` value you'll output the same `t` value calculated for the entire time-bucket.

As far as I understand your query should look like:

```
col.aggregate([
  // Pre-filter
  { $match: { /* ... */ } },

  // Pre-sort to aid in grouping
  { $sort: { c: 1, y: 1, m: 1, a: 1 },      

  // Group by month, customer and `a` to find unique `a` values and their totals
  { $group: { 
     _id: { c: '$c', y: '$y', m: '$m', a: '$a' },
     t: { $sum: 1 } 
    }
  },

  // Not sure if another sort is required at this point, I'd assume MongoDB
  // is smart enough to understand we're grouping by a subset of the original 
  // grouping key

  // Group by month and customer to count unique `a` values and grand total 
  { $group: {
    _id: { c: '$_id.c', y: '$_id.y', m: '$_id.m' },
    a: { sum: 1 }, // number of unique `a` values in group
    t: { sum: '$t' } // rolled-up total of all `a`-totals in group
  },

  // You can tack on further groupings by year and customer here,
  // although I believe these would be better done in the UI layer
]);
```

So basically, the beginning of the pipeline with the unwinding and re-grouping, and the intermediate sorts, might be slowing you down. See if this version performs better and try to add sorts between groupings if they help.

Comment: Thank you @Avish. I reduced my aggregation query as per your recommendation. The output data is the same, but the timing is very close as well (~17sec vs ~17.5sec)

Comment: ...but now you have less steps to worry about :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying an index on y, m, and d (year, month, date is it?) on that order, since those are known to be int, versus the current one that c which can be an int or a string. Since the data is time based, might make more sense as well.